# Task not Serializable exception on converting dataset to red

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have DataSet which looks like below:

```
dataset.show(10)

|   features|
+-----------+
|[14.378858]|
|[14.388442]|
|[14.384361]|
|[14.386358]|
|[14.390068]|
|[14.423256]|
|[14.425567]|
|[14.434074]|
|[14.437667]|
|[14.445997]|
+-----------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

But, when I am trying to convert this `DataSet` into `RDD` using `.rdd` like below :

```
val myRDD = dataset.rdd
```

I'm getting exception like below:

```
Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.runtime.LazyRef, value: LazyRef thunk)
    - element of array (index: 2)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2:(Lscala/Function1;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;Lscala/runtime/LazyRef;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef
```

Clearly indicates runtime version mismatch issue. You have not mentioned your spark version...

[This is scala version issue downgrade to scala 2.11  it should work](http://Spark%20runs%20on%20Java%208,%20Python%202.7+/3.4+%20and%20R%203.1+.%20For%20the%20Scala%20API,%20Spark%202.4.5%20uses%20Scala%202.12.%20You%20will%20need%20to%20use%20a%20compatible%20Scala%20version%20(2.12.x).)

See this version table from this url https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
and change your scala version appropriately.

[image]

Comment: This is scala version link is not correct. Can you paste the correct link?

Comment: Downgrading the version did solve my problem. But I'm unable to understand how this error java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef suggests that its scala version error?

Comment: Scala compilation was done correctly but.rumtime it's not able to serialize datastructre. That's why not serialization error. Since new Scala version had the same classes it was able to compile. Scala is not backword compatible. That's the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue where my scala version was 2.12.2, on moving to 2.12.8 it solved the issue.